# What is the difference between Sakkaya Ditthi and Attanuditthi?

Tags: theravada

What is the difference between Sakkhya Ditthi and Attanuditthi?

I have asked the same question at the Dhamma Wheel topic: [Sakkaya Ditthi is not self-view!!](https://dhammawheel.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=31361)

---

In my opinion or view, SN 35.166 ([Samyutta 34.16.11.(166)](http://awake.kiev.ua/dhamma/tipitaka/2Sutta-Pitaka/3Samyutta-Nikaya/Samyutta4/34-Salayatana-Samyutta/16-Nandikkhayavaggo-e.html)) says Sakkāya Ditthi - Self View is not the self view but it is taking this existence or five aggregate as pleasurable.

> *34. 16. 11.*
>
> *(166) Sakkāya - Self View*
>
> *1. At one time the Blessed One lived in Jīvaka's mango orchard in Rajagaha.*
>
> *2. Then a certain monk approached the Blessed One, worshipped and sat on a side.*
>
> *3. Sitting on a side that monk said to the Blessed One: “Venerable sir, knowing how and seeing how does the self view get dispelled?”*
>
> *4-9. “Monk, by knowing and seeing unpleasantness, in the eye self view gets dispelled Monk, by knowing and seeing unpleasantness in
>   forms, eye-consciousness, eye-contact and whatever feelings pleasant,
>   unpleasant or neither unpleasant nor pleasant born of eye-contact,
>   self view gets dispelled. Repeat for ear, nose, tongue, body, and
>   mind*
>
> *10. “Monk, knowing and seeing thus self view gets dispelled.”*

In my view or opinion, taking:

- Anicca (the impermanent) as Nicca (permanent) is wrong view ie: Micchaditthi
- Dukkha (the unsatisfactory) as Adhukha (happiness) is Sakkayaditthi
- Anatta (not-self) as Atta (self) is Attanuditthi.

Answer (score 2):

**They are just the synonym**.

- Sakkāya is an object of anu-diṭṭhi. So, [sakkāyadiṭṭhisutta](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=17&item=356&items=2) and
  [attānudiṭṭhisutta](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=17&item=358&items=2) have the same content. [This](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/v.php?B=17&A=4246&Z=4271&eng=metta_e) is the english translated version of those suttas,
  attānudiṭṭhisutta is next of sakkāyadiṭṭhisutta.

---

Your 3 suttas, [which near by each other](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/attha/v.php?B=18&A=3842&Z=3899&eng=metta_e), describing each other like this:

**Diṭṭhi** means misunderstanding of causes and effects, clinging-aggregates which is anattā as **attā**.

**Anu** is prefix which means often.

**Micchā** is prefix which means mistake.

**Sakkāya** is a name of clinging-aggregates follow to many sutta, such as Sutta. Ma. Mū. [Cūḷavedallasuttaṃ](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/read/v.php?B=12&A=9420&Z=9601&eng=metta_e2).

> **These clinging-aggregates are the Sakkāya described by the Blessed One**.

So, **sakkāya-micchā-anu-diṭṭhi** means **often mis-understanding**,  micchā-anu-diṭṭhi (verb act as noun), **of sakkāya** (object), causes and effects, clinging-aggregates, which is anattā, as attā. *See note0 below for more information.*

---

**Note0:** *(I have to use image, because I can not make underline in stackexchange. The same format are relating to the same format.
)*

> [image]

Above pāli appear in these suttas:

Sutta. Saṃ. Saḷa. [Isidattasutta](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/read/v.php?B=18&A=7280&Z=7366&eng=metta_e):

> [image]

For "[dvāsaṭṭhidiṭṭhigatāni brahmajāle](http://84000.org/tipitaka/read/v.php?book=21&item=243&items=11&A=1&eng=suttacentral)" above refer to micchā-diṭṭhi in Aṅ. (2): catukkanipāto [saṅghabhedakasutta](http://84000.org/tipitaka/read/v.php?B=21&A=6387&Z=6568&eng=suttacentral):

**brahmajāle:**

> [image]

**saṅghabhedakasutta:**

> [image]

**So, what I said:**

> [image]

**It is completely from pāli.**

---

**Note1:** Sakkāya is not only internal, because there are internal clinging-aggregates, internal sakkāya, and external clinging-aggregates, external sakkāya, which are contemplating by the practitioner in [Cūlavedallasutta](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/read/v.php?B=12&A=9420&Z=9601&eng=metta_e2) and Sutta. Ma. Mū. Sacca-pabba of [Satipaṭṭhānasuttaṃ](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/r.php?B=12&A=1754&eng=suttacentral) (<< this link is a good translation of this sutta).

> they meditate by observing **an aspect of the principle inside and outside**.

The inside and outside aspect of the principle in this term is sakkāya (clinging aggregates), sakkāyasamudayo, sakkāyanirodho, and sakkāyanirodhagāminīpaṭipadā.

---

**Note2**: **Santo kāyo sakkāyo.** Kāya, clinging-aggregates, is sacca, santa, vijjānana, the reality, truth, possible to arise in causes and effects cycle. So, buddha said sakkāya is sacca and clinging-aggregates in Sutta. Saṃ. Kha. [Sakkāyasutta](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=17&item=284&items=5)<sup>[[trans]](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/v.php?B=17&A=3512&Z=3529&eng=metta_e)</sup>.

"Sakko kāyo sakkāyo" and **"para kāyo sakkāyo"** is allowed in Ma. Mū. Sacca-pabba of [Satipaṭṭhānasuttaṃ](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/r.php?B=12&A=1754&eng=suttacentral) as an *internal anupassī*, **but it is not the primary meaning when compare to Sutta. Saṃ. Kha. [Sakkāyasutta](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=17&item=284&items=5)<sup>[[trans]](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/v.php?B=17&A=3512&Z=3529&eng=metta_e)</sup>, which sakkāya meaning is defined by buddha directly**. And "para kāyo sakkāyo" never found in any where else except in  Satipaṭṭhānasuttaṃ.

So, if you use **"sakko kāyo sakkāyo"** in [Sakkāyasutta](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=17&item=284&items=5), Sakkāyasutta, which has only **sakko**, will conflict with Sacca-pabba of [Satipaṭṭhānasuttaṃ](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/r.php?B=12&A=1754&eng=suttacentral), which has **both sakko and paro**.

But by the **"Santo kāyo sakkāyo"**, there is no conflict like that between the **co-context** sutta, such as [micchādiṭṭhisutta](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=17&item=355&items=1&preline=0&pagebreak=0&modeTY=1), [sakkāyadiṭṭhisutta](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=17&item=356&items=2), and [attānudiṭṭhisutta](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=17&item=358&items=2), which using the same context and [near by each other](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=17&item=355&items=3&mode=bracket). **Also, there is no conflict between those sutta and the faraway suttas** such as Sutta. Saṃ. Kha. [Sakkāyasutta](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=17&item=284&items=5),  Sutta. Ma. Mū. Sacca-pabba of [Satipaṭṭhānasuttaṃ](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/r.php?B=12&A=1754&eng=suttacentral), and Sutta. Ma. Mū. [Cūḷavedallasuttaṃ](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/read/v.php?B=12&A=9420&Z=9601&eng=metta_e2).

---

**Note3**: Your 3 suttas, [which near by each other](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/attha/v.php?B=18&A=3842&Z=3899&eng=metta_e), describing each other. Mostly words of them can use in the other sutta, such as anicca, dukkha, anatta, of these 3 sutta contexts all refering to saṅkhata (clinging-aggregates), which means arisen by causes. So, it can use to explain each other like appeared in Vinaya. Mahā (1) [Anattalakkhaṇasutta](http://84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka1/v.php?B=04&A=479&Z=575&eng=metta_e):

> 42. ‘Now what do you think, O bhikkhus, is the body permanent or perishable?’
>
> ‘It is perishable **(anicca)**, Lord.’
>
> ‘And that which is perishable, does that cause pain or joy?’
>
> ‘It causes pain **(dukkha)**, Lord.’
>
> ‘And that which is perishable, painful, subject to change, is it
>   possible to regard that in this way. ‘This is mine, this am I, this is
>   my self **(atta)**?’ ‘That is impossible, Lord.’

So, those 3 suttas is synonym of each other. For the example:

You never have to see "I often(1) mis(2)-understand(3) of you-ahaṃ tuvaṃ micchā(2) anu(1)-passāmi(3)" sentence. But is it the right, if I tell you A, B, and C have the same meaning?:

A: I often understand of you as permanent person.

B: I misunderstand of you as permanent person.

C: I understand of you as my dear forever (misunderstanding sakkāya as attā).

In this case the buddha can predict, because buddha maybe his teacher, the listening-bhikkhu will enlighten by **animitta-vimokkha**, so the buddha taught  impermanence to him. And this bhikku maybe memorized micchādiṭṭhi from buddha before, so the buddha taught micchādiṭṭhi in this sutta. **If the buddha teach the other words, they cannot enlighten, because the listening maybe never memorized before**.

It looks like when I said หนึ่งคูณสองเท่ากับสอง, you cannot enlighten what I said. But if I said "1x2=2", you can get it.

This is the same way which [atthakathā](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/atthapali/read_rm.php?B=13&A=1&w=bujjhanak%C4%81na%E1%B9%83%20ajjh%C4%81sayena%20vutta%E1%B9%83) described  SN Salāyatanavagga [aniccatādisutta](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka2/v.php?B=18&A=1&Z=25&eng=metta_e):

> Iti idaṃ suttaṃ chasu ajjhattikāyatanesu tīṇi lakkhaṇāni dassetvā
>   kathite bujjhanakānaṃ ajjhāsayena vuttaṃ.
>
> For these 3 sutta, buddha taught 3 characterizes of 6 inner-āyatana
>   **depend on the enlightening-possibility of each listening-bhikkhu.**

For more information, you can see [naya in netti](http://tipitaka.wikia.com/wiki/Netti-Part_V.Chapter-iii).

---

**Note4:**

[image]

---

**Note5:** Sakkāya is not similar to sakkāya-diṭṭhi in mostly suttas such as [sakkāyasutta](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/pitaka_item/roman_item_s.php?book=17&item=284&items=5).

**Sakkāya** is 5 aggregates, which is engaging by diṭṭhi-clinging (diṭṭhi-upādāna).

But **sakkāya-diṭṭhi** is diṭṭhi-clinging, which engaging 5 aggregates.

So, mostly english version, which I random checked, translated wrong as "self view (sakkāya-diṭṭhi)", but it should be just "sakkāya".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74087/discussion-on-answer-by-bonn-what-is-the-difference-between-sakkaya-ditthi-and-a).

Comment: @ChrisW I guess you will like  the note0 and note4, which I added above, because It is very clear, and provable.

Answer (score 1):

I think the commonly-accepted definition of sakkāyadiṭṭhi comes from passages [like this](https://suttacentral.net/pi/mn44) in MN 44:

> Kathaṃ panāyye, sakkāyadiṭṭhi hotī”ti? “Idhāvuso visākha, assutavā puthujjano, ariyānaṃ adassāvī ariyadhammassa akovido ariyadhamme avinīto, sappurisānaṃ adassāvī sap­purisa­dhammassa akovido sap­purisa­dhamme avinīto, rūpaṃ attato samanupassati, rūpavantaṃ vā attānaṃ, attani vā rūpaṃ, rūpasmiṃ vā attānaṃ. Vedanaṃ … pe … saññaṃsaññaṃ: ? … saṅkhāre … viññāṇaṃ attato samanupassati, viññāṇavantaṃ vā attānaṃ, attani vā viññāṇaṃ, viññāṇasmiṃ vā attānaṃ. Evaṃ kho, āvuso visākha, sakkāyadiṭṭhi hotī”ti.

I think, in summary, that is saying that it is wrong view to identify the five aggregates with the *atta* -- the "self" (or, soul).

So maybe it is no surprise, and not wrong, that sakkāyadiṭṭhi is called "self-view" or "identity-view".

[Here's a translation](https://accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.044.than.html):

> "But, lady, how does self-identification come about?"
>
> "There is the case, friend Visakha, where an uninstructed, run-of-the-mill person — who has no regard for noble ones, is not well-versed or disciplined in their Dhamma; who has no regard for men of integrity, is not well-versed or disciplined in their Dhamma — assumes form (the body) to be the self, or the self as possessing form, or form as in the self, or the self as in form.
>
> "He assumes feeling to be the self...
>
> "He assumes perception to be the self...
>
> "He assumes (mental) fabrications to be the self...
>
> "He assumes consciousness to be the self, or the self as possessing consciousness, or consciousness as in the self, or the self as in consciousness. This is how self-identification comes about."

But it might be easy to read an English translation like "self-view" or "self-identification", and assume it's talking all about the *self*.

Instead it may be talking mostly about the *aggregates*, i.e. "wrong to view the *aggregates* as self".

Perhaps it ought to be called "a wrong view of aggregates".

---

But anyway, perhaps it isn't right to say, "Sakkaya Ditthi is not self-view!!"; nor, that it means "taking the aggregates as pleasurable" -- because instead, in MN 44, it explicitly says, "taking the aggregates as self".

---

Logically, attanuditthi is presumably some kind of wrong view regarding the self (whether it's the same wrong view of self, or a different wrong view of self, I don't know -- I haven't looked up the sutta reference[s] for it).